# Using javascript to change gradient colors in animated background

Tags: javascript, animation, gradient

I am attempting to add a button to my website that will change one of two gradient colors in a linear-gradient animation. The animation is currently working and runs in the background of my website.

The animation javascript looks like this

```
var angle = 0 

var changeBackground = function (){
angle = angle + 1

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle +"deg, #000000, #666"
requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

changeBackground ()
```

I want to add this html button. When you click it, the color #666 in the animation above gets switched out for #d22c1f.

```
<button class="Btn" id="myBtn">Click</button>
```

I found this "https://codepen.io/Chrono79/pen/YxyJqw" which is very close, but I am having trouble implementing this code into my animation. Also I just want it to switch between two colors and in this example it generates a random rgb color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A color variable together with an event listener on your button, and you can toggle between 2 colors

Stack snippet

```js
var angle = 0, color = "#666";

var changeBackground = function() {
  angle = angle + 1
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle + "deg, #000000, " + color;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

changeBackground()

document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  color = (color != "#666") ? "#666" : "#d22c1f";
})
```

```html
<button class="Btn" id="myBtn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this implementation?

```
var angle = 0;

var changeBackground = function (){
  angle += 1;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle +"deg, 
  #000000, #666"
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    angle += 1;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle +"deg, 
#000000, #666"
    if (angle % 90 === 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 5)
}
```

https://jsbin.com/xamolumove/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The spelling error was a mistake when posting here. The above animation already runs. I edited the post to be more specific.